# MIPS bubble sorting

Tags: mips

I want to make bubble sorting program by using MIPS.
This is what I want to make.

```
int arr[] = [2, 0];
int temp = arr[1];
arr[1] = arr[0];
arr[0] = temp;
```

This is what I made.

```
la   $t0, Input_data #Input_data: .word 2, 0

lw   $s0, 0($t0) # 2
lw   $s1, 4($t0) # 0

lw   $s6, 4($t0) #0
sw   $s6, 0($t0) #2 -> 0
sw   $s0, 4($t0) #0 -> 2
```

I thought that it's result will be 000000, 000002 but, only 000002..
I don't know why...:(
How can I fix it??

Comment: What do you mean by _"only 000002"_? And what is the purpose of using `$s6`? You already have that value in `$s1`.

Comment: Yes, I don't know why 000000 is disappeared. And I use $s6 as temp.

Comment: It's unclear what you mean by _"disappeared"_. Disappeared from where? And you don't need a temp, since storing a register to memory doesn't change the value of that register.